# Why does the compiler result an error of "cycle detected when processing ..."?

Tags: rust, traits, vulkan

For context, I am using the Vulkano library to make a game, so I have omitted all Vulkano imports. I was trying to use the `render()` function to render my world, but I am confused with the error because I have not reference any implementations from `world.rs` into `mesh.rs`. I have just started using Rust for a few months now, so I may still be confused with the Traits and stuff.

Project Source Directory

```
src
  - main.rs  // imports all the module file in the directory
  - mesh.rs  // does not import `world.rs` module
  - world.rs  // imports the `mesh.rs` module
  - ...
```

mesh.rs

```rust
pub trait Mesh {
    type Vertex;

    fn vert_data(&self, texture: &TextureAtlas, position: [f32; 3]) -> Vec<Self::Vertex>;  // returns the vertex data
    fn ind_data(&self, index: u32) -> Vec<u32>;  // returns the index data
}

pub struct Cube {
    top: [u16; 2],
    bottom: [u16; 2],
    left: [u16; 2],
    right: [u16; 2],
    front: [u16; 2],
    back: [u16; 2],
}

impl Cube {
    /* ... */
}

impl Mesh for Cube {
    /* ... */
}
```

I have checked other imports in the `world.rs`, but none of them reimports `world.rs`.

world.rs

```rust
use crate::mesh::Cube;
use crate::mesh::Mesh;

pub struct World<V, M> {
    name: String,
    chunk: Vec<Chunk<V, M>>,
}

impl<V, M> World<V, M> {
    pub fn render(device: Arc<Device>, txtr: &TextureAtlas) -> (Arc<CpuAccessibleBuffer<[dyn Mesh<Vertex=CubeVtx>]>>, Arc<CpuAccessibleBuffer<[_]>>) {
    }

    /* ... */
}
```

Error:

```
error[E0391]: cycle detected when processing `world::<impl at src\world.rs:24:1: 88:2>::render`
  --> src\world.rs:34:5
   |
34 |     pub fn render(device: Arc<Device>, txtr: &TextureAtlas) -> (Arc<CpuAccessibleBuffer<[dyn Mesh<Vertex=CubeVtx>]>>, Arc<CpuAccessibleBuffer<[_]>>) {
   |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   |
note: ...which requires processing `world::<impl at src\world.rs:24:1: 88:2>::render`...
  --> src\world.rs:34:5
   |
34 |     pub fn render(device: Arc<Device>, txtr: &TextureAtlas) -> (Arc<CpuAccessibleBuffer<[dyn Mesh<Vertex=CubeVtx>]>>, Arc<CpuAccessibleBuffer<[_]>>) {
   |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
note: ...which requires processing `mesh::Cube`...
  --> src\mesh.rs:31:1
   |
31 | pub struct Cube {
   | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   = note: ...which requires computing the variances for items in this crate...
   = note: ...which again requires processing `world::<impl at src\world.rs:24:1: 88:2>::render`, completing the cycle
note: cycle used when collecting item types in module `world`
  --> src\main.rs:50:1
   |
50 | mod world;
   | ^^^^^^^^^^
```

I was suspecting it might have something to do with the trait `Mesh`.

I have tried to delete the `target` directory and separated the implementation of `Mesh` to separate file leaving only the trait in the original file.

Comment: I found that you have to set the Associated Type as static.

Comment: Ok, make your findings into an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I found myself very naive towards Rust's complex trait system. The only change I had to do was to add a `'static` lifetime on to the associate type `Vertex` which fixes the problem which is really confusing the fact that the error shows as a circular reference.

```
pub trait Mesh {
    type Vertex: 'static;

    fn vert_data(&self, texture: &TextureAtlas, position: [f32; 3]) -> Vec<Self::Vertex>;  // returns the vertex data
    fn ind_data(&self, index: u32) -> Vec<u32>;  // returns the index data
}
```